# Scraping .asp site with R

Tags: html, xml, r, web-scraping

I'm scraping `http://www.progarchives.com/album.asp?id=` and get a warning message:

> Warning message:
>   XML content does not seem to be XML:
>   http://www.progarchives.com/album.asp?id=2
>   http://www.progarchives.com/album.asp?id=3      http://www.progarchives.com/album.asp?id=4
>   http://www.progarchives.com/album.asp?id=5

The scraper works for each page separately but not for the urls `b1=2:b2=1000`.

```
 library(RCurl)
 library(XML)

getUrls <- function(b1,b2){
   root="http://www.progarchives.com/album.asp?id="
   urls <- NULL
     for (bandid in b1:b2){
   urls <- c(urls,(paste(root,bandid,sep="")))
  }
  return(urls)
}

prog.arch.scraper <- function(url){
SOURCE <- getUrls(b1=2,b2=1000)
PARSED <- htmlParse(SOURCE)
album <- xpathSApply(PARSED,"//h1[1]",xmlValue)
date <- xpathSApply(PARSED,"//strong[1]",xmlValue)
band <- xpathSApply(PARSED,"//h2[1]",xmlValue)
return(c(band,album,date))
}

prog.arch.scraper(urls)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an alternate approach with `rvest` and `dplyr`:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(pbapply)

base_url <- "http://www.progarchives.com/album.asp?id=%s"

get_album_info <- function(id) {

  pg <- html(sprintf(base_url, id))
  data.frame(album=pg %>% html_nodes(xpath="//h1[1]") %>% html_text(),
             date=pg %>% html_nodes(xpath="//strong[1]") %>% html_text(),
             band=pg %>% html_nodes(xpath="//h2[1]") %>% html_text(),
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

}

albums <- bind_rows(pblapply(2:10, get_album_info))

head(albums)

## Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
## 
##                        album                           date      band
## 1                    FOXTROT Studio Album, released in 1972   Genesis
## 2              NURSERY CRYME Studio Album, released in 1971   Genesis
## 3               GENESIS LIVE         Live, released in 1973   Genesis
## 4        A TRICK OF THE TAIL Studio Album, released in 1976   Genesis
## 5 FROM GENESIS TO REVELATION Studio Album, released in 1969   Genesis
## 6           GRATUITOUS FLASH Studio Album, released in 1984 Abel Ganz
```

I didn't feel like barraging the site with a ton of reqs so bump up the sequence for your use. `pblapply` gives you a free progress bar.

To be kind to the site (esp since it doesn't explicitly prohibit scraping) you might want to throw a `Sys.sleep(10)` at the end of the `get_album_info` function.

**UPDATE**

To handle server errors (in this case `500`, but it'll work for others, too), you can use `try`:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(pbapply)
library(data.table)

base_url <- "http://www.progarchives.com/album.asp?id=%s"

get_album_info <- function(id) {

  pg <- try(html(sprintf(base_url, id)), silent=TRUE)

  if (inherits(pg, "try-error")) {
    data.frame(album=character(0), date=character(0), band=character(0))
  } else {
    data.frame(album=pg %>% html_nodes(xpath="//h1[1]") %>% html_text(),
               date=pg %>% html_nodes(xpath="//strong[1]") %>% html_text(),
               band=pg %>% html_nodes(xpath="//h2[1]") %>% html_text(),
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  }

}

albums <- rbindlist(pblapply(c(9:10, 23, 28, 29, 30), get_album_info))

##                       album                           date         band
## 1: THE DANGERS OF STRANGERS Studio Album, released in 1988    Abel Ganz
## 2:    THE DEAFENING SILENCE Studio Album, released in 1994    Abel Ganz
## 3:             AD INFINITUM Studio Album, released in 1998 Ad Infinitum
```

You won't get any entries for the errant pages (in this case it just returns id 9, 10 and 30's entries).

Comment: Thanks! It worked except I get an error message saying there is no function ` "bind_rows"`. I re-installed all the packages but still no luck.

Comment: `rbindlist` did the trick. I've been meaning to get into `rvest` for some time so your code got me to look into it in more detail. Thanks @hrbrmstr. One further question though, what does `sprintf` actually do inside the html function?

Comment: There are roughly 48,000 pages I'm interested in scraping but I noticed the scraper stops when it comes across broken pages, i.e `Internal Error`. One way of dealing with them is to check each page an note which ones are broken and concatenate the good ones inside the `albums` object but that's time consuming. Do you have any suggestions for dealing with broken pages? Cheers.

Comment: `Error in parse.response(r, parser, encoding = encoding) : server error: (500) Internal Server Error` when the sequence includes broken pages. Problem is, there's no way of knowing which ones are bad. So far, I've identified 23, 28, 29, 34, 44, 86, 134 ,165 ,188 ,252 ,332 ,350 ,351 ,377 ,378 ,531 ,688, 758, 816, 818, 876, 886:889, 937, 960, 961, 976, 1002, 1054,  1084, 1103, 1116,etc. There are probably hundreds more broken. Check out `http://www.progarchives.com/album.asp?id=2347` for an example.

Comment: Update to handle server errors in answer. Also added `rbindlist`

Comment: You're a legend. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `xpathApply()`, you could subset the first node in the node sets of each path and call `xmlValue()` on that.  Here's what I came up with,

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl) 

## define the urls and xpath queries
urls <- sprintf("http://www.progarchives.com/album.asp?id=%s", 2:10)
path <- c(album = "//h1", date = "//strong", band = "//h2")

## define a re-usable curl handle for the c-level nodes
curl <- getCurlHandle()
## allocate the result list
out <- vector("list", length(urls))

## do the work    
for(u in urls) {
    content <- getURL(u, curl = curl)
    doc <- htmlParse(content, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
    out[[u]] <- lapply(path, function(x) xmlValue(doc[x][[1]]))
    free(doc)
}

## structure the result
data.table::rbindlist(out)
#                         album                           date      band
# 1:                    FOXTROT Studio Album, released in 1972   Genesis
# 2:              NURSERY CRYME Studio Album, released in 1971   Genesis
# 3:               GENESIS LIVE         Live, released in 1973   Genesis
# 4:        A TRICK OF THE TAIL Studio Album, released in 1976   Genesis
# 5: FROM GENESIS TO REVELATION Studio Album, released in 1969   Genesis
# 6:           GRATUITOUS FLASH Studio Album, released in 1984 Abel Ganz
# 7:          GULLIBLES TRAVELS Studio Album, released in 1985 Abel Ganz
# 8:   THE DANGERS OF STRANGERS Studio Album, released in 1988 Abel Ganz
# 9:      THE DEAFENING SILENCE Studio Album, released in 1994 Abel Ganz
```

**Update:** To handle the `id` queries do not exist, we can write a condition with `RCurl::url.exists()` that handles the bad ones.  So the following function `getAlbums()` returns a character vector of the either the fetched xml values or `NA`, depending on the status of the url. You can change that if you want, of course. That was just a method that came to mind in the wee hours.

```
getAlbums <- function(url, id = numeric(), xPath = list()) {
    urls <- sprintf("%s?id=%d", url, id)
    curl <- getCurlHandle()
    out <- vector("list", length(urls))
    for(u in urls) {
        out[[u]] <- if(url.exists(u)) {
            content <- getURL(u, curl = curl)
            doc <- htmlParse(content, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
            lapply(path, function(x) xmlValue(doc[x][[1]]))
        } else {
            warning(sprintf("returning 'NA' for urls[%d] ", id[urls == u]))
            structure(as.list(path[NA]), names = names(path))
        }
        if(exists("doc")) free(doc)
    }
    data.table::rbindlist(out)
}

url <- "http://www.progarchives.com/album.asp"
id <- c(9:10, 23, 28, 29, 30)
path <- c(album = "//h1", date = "//strong", band = "//h2")
getAlbums(url, id, path)
#                       album                           date         band
# 1: THE DANGERS OF STRANGERS Studio Album, released in 1988    Abel Ganz
# 2:    THE DEAFENING SILENCE Studio Album, released in 1994    Abel Ganz
# 3:                       NA                             NA           NA
# 4:                       NA                             NA           NA
# 5:                       NA                             NA           NA
# 6:             AD INFINITUM Studio Album, released in 1998 Ad Infinitum
# 
# Warning messages:
# 1: In albums(url, id, path) : returning 'NA' for urls[23] 
# 2: In albums(url, id, path) : returning 'NA' for urls[28] 
# 3: In albums(url, id, path) : returning 'NA' for urls[29]
```

Comment: @ Richard Scriven. Thanks! This works fine except I run into the same problem as above with the broken links.